# How to fix ' raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url) ValueError: unknown url type: '''

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

So I have been following along some videos to learn python, but can't get rid of this error. I have experience in other languages so I'm usually fine to fix errors, but no matter what I do, I either get the same error or something different.

I've tried switching the argument from 'xml' to 'lxml', but this only changes the error that I get

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request



req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://pythonprogramming.net/')


xml = BeautifulSoup(req, 'xml')

for item in xml.findAll('link'):
    url = item.text
    news = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    print(news)
```

Ideally, this would print out some of the text within link tags, but instead, I get the following errors -

Error while using xml -

```
  File "/Users/rodrigo/Desktop/ALL/Programming/Python/Python Web Programming/Working with HTML/scrapingParagraphData.py", line 13, in <module>
    news = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 548, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1387, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: @media (min-width>
```

Error while using lxml -

```
  File "/Users/rodrigo/Desktop/ALL/Programming/Python/Python Web Programming/Working with HTML/scrapingParagraphData.py", line 13, in <module>
    news = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 510, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
ValueError: unknown url type: ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is targeting link elements and is extracting text rather than href so there is no known protocol to work with.

Even if you extracted the href they are relative so you would still have a problem with unknown protocol.

`item['href']` would give:

```
/static/favicon.ico
/static/css/materialize.min.css
https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons
/static/css/bootstrap.css
```

I don't think you are after these type of links. If you were after the tutorial links then you need something that targets those elements e.g.

```
tutorial_links = ['https://pythonprogramming.net' + i['href'] for i in xml.select('.waves-light.btn')]
```

I would probably rename the assignment variable in  `BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')` to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.urlopen('http://pythonprogramming.net/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
tutorial_links = ['https://pythonprogramming.net' + i['href'] for i in xml.select('.waves-light.btn')]
```

Comment: My problem was that I had copied the code exactly, just switched the websites because the website that was used in the tutorial was not working. The code that I have is exactly the same as the one in the tutorial, but I can not seem to get it to work. I believe that the issue lies with - news = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read() - but I'm not sure

Comment: perhaps share the url for the tutorial?

Comment: Here is the url, but I dont think you will have access -https://stoneriverelearning.com/courses/19051/lectures/273869